# CakePHP Model uses the wrong fields in SQL statements!

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a bunch of models with various associations set up between them and seems like Cakephp at times executes incorrect SQL statement and cause MySQL to barf.

For example, if I have two models, Comment and Tag and a code like this:

```
$this->Comment->id = 5;
$this->Comment->saveField('read_count', 3);
```

yields SQL statement:

```
UPDATE comments SET read_count = 3 WHERE Tag.id = 3;
```

It doesn't happen all the time but it eventually happens since I am doing everything in a tight loop.

Please help. This really makes me question my decision to go with Cake since this sounds bad.

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**
I just ran into the problem and here is the faulty SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `albums_songs` AS `AlbumSong`   WHERE `ArtistGenre`.`id` = 26482
```

AlbumSong and ArtistGenre are two completely separate tables and they are not related at all.

**EDIT 2**
Just ran into another failure. The code is:

```
$this->Song->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Song.artist_id' => 30188, 'Song.name' => 'Pal Pal (By.Tarkhanz)'), 'fields' => array('Song.id')))
```

While the generated SQL is:

```
SELECT `Song`.`id` FROM `songs` AS `Song`   WHERE `Artist`.`name` = 'Annie Villeneuve'    LIMIT 1
```

As you can see no were in the conditions do I specify an Artist.name yet the SQL generated is looking at it.

**EDIT 3**
Another example failure. Call is as followed:

```
$this->Song->id = $song_id;
$library_count = $this->Song->field('Song.library_count');
```

Yet the SQL is:

```
SELECT `Song`.`library_count` FROM `songs` AS `Song`   WHERE `Artist`.`name` = 'Mazikana_Ragheb_Allama'    LIMIT 1
```

where Artist.name is not a column of Song as it belongs to the Artist model.

Thanks.

**EDIT 4**

```
models/album.php

    <?php
    class Album extends AppModel {
            var $name = 'Album';
            var $belongsTo = array(
                    'Artist' => array(
                            'className' => 'Artist',
                            'foreignKey' => 'artist_id',
                            'conditions' => '',
                            'fields' => '',
                            'order' => ''
                    )
            );

            var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
                    'Song' => array(
                            'className' => 'Song',
                            'joinTable' => 'albums_songs',
                            'foreignKey' => 'album_id',
                            'associationForeignKey' => 'song_id',
                            'unique' => true,
                            'conditions' => '',
                            'fields' => '',
                            'order' => '',
                            'limit' => '',
                            'offset' => '',
                            'finderQuery' => '',
                            'deleteQuery' => '',
                            'insertQuery' => ''
                    )
            );

            var $hasMany = array(
                    'AlbumSong' => array(
                            'className' => 'AlbumSong',
                            'foreignKey' => 'album_id',
                            'dependent' => false,
                            'conditions' => '',
                            'fields' => '',
                            'order' => '',
                            'limit' => '',
                            'offset' => '',
                            'exclusive' => '',
                            'finderQuery' => '',
                            'counterQuery' => ''
                    )
            );
    }

    ?>

    models/album_song.php

    <?php
    class AlbumSong extends AppModel {
            var $name = 'AlbumSong';
            var $useTable = 'albums_songs';
            var $belongsTo = array(
                    'Song' => array(
                            'className' => 'Song',
                            'foreignKey' => 'song_id',
                            'conditions' => '',
                            'fields' => '',
                            'order' => ''
                    ),
                    'Album' => array(
                            'className' => 'Album',
                            'foreignKey' => 'album_id',
                            'conditions' => '',
                            'fields' => '',
                            'order' => ''
                    )
            );
    }

    ?>

    models/artist.php
    <?php
    class Artist extends AppModel {
            var $name = 'Artist';
            var $hasMany = array(
                    'Album' => array(
                            'className' => 'Album',
                            'foreignKey' => 'artist_id',
                            'dependent' => false,
                            'conditions' => '',
                            'fields' => '',
                            'order' => '',
                            'limit' => '',
                            'offset' => '',
                            'exclusive' => '',
                            'finderQuery' => '',
                            'counterQuery' => ''
                    ),
                    'Song' => array(
                            'className' => 'Song',
                            'foreignKey' => 'artist_id',
                            'dependent' => false,
                            'conditions' => '',
                            'fields' => '',
                            'order' => '',
                            'limit' => '',
                            'offset' => '',
                            'exclusive' => '',
                            'finderQuery' => '',
                            'counterQuery' => ''
                    ),
                    'ArtistGenre' => array(
                            'className' => 'ArtistGenre',
                            'foreignKey' => 'artist_id',
                            'dependent' => false,
                            'conditions' => '',
                            'fields' => '',
                            'order' => '',
                            'limit' => '',
                            'offset' => '',
                            'exclusive' => '',
                            'finderQuery' => '',
                            'counterQuery' => ''
                    )
            );
    }

    ?>

    models/artist_genre.php

    <?php
    class ArtistGenre extends AppModel {
            var $name = 'ArtistGenre';
            var $useTable = 'artists_genres';
            var $belongsTo = array(
                    'Artist' => array(
                            'className' => 'Artist',
                            'foreignKey' => 'artist_id',
                            'conditions' => '',
                            'fields' => '',
                            'order' => ''
                    ),
                    'Genre' => array(
                            'className' => 'Genre',
                            'foreignKey' => 'genre_id',
                            'conditions' => '',
                            'fields' => '',
                            'order' => ''
                    )
            );
    }

    ?>

    models/genre.php

    <?php
    class Genre extends AppModel {
            var $name = 'Genre';
            var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
                    'Artist' => array(
                            'className' => 'Artist',
                            'joinTable' => 'artists_genres',
                            'foreignKey' => 'genre_id',
                            'associationForeignKey' => 'artist_id',
                            'unique' => true,
                            'conditions' => '',
                            'fields' => '',
                            'order' => '',
                            'limit' => '',
                            'offset' => '',
                            'finderQuery' => '',
                            'deleteQuery' => '',
                            'insertQuery' => ''
                    )
            );

            var $hasMany = array(
                    'ArtistGenre' => array(
                            'className' => 'ArtistGenre',
                            'foreignKey' => 'genre_id',
                            'dependent' => false,
                            'conditions' => '',
                            'fields' => '',
                            'order' => '',
                            'limit' => '',
                            'offset' => '',
                            'exclusive' => '',
                            'finderQuery' => '',
                            'counterQuery' => ''
                    )
            );
    }

    ?>

    models/song.php

    <?php
    class Song extends AppModel {
            var $name = 'Song';
            var $belongsTo = array(
                    'Artist' => array(
                            'className' => 'Artist',
                            'foreignKey' => 'artist_id',
                            'conditions' => '',
                            'fields' => '',
                            'order' => ''
                    )
            );
            /*
            var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
                    'Album' => array(
                            'className' => 'Album',
                            'joinTable' => 'albums_songs',
                            'foreignKey' => 'song_id',
                            'associationForeignKey' => 'album_id',
                            'unique' => true,
                            'conditions' => '',
                            'fields' => '',
                            'order' => '',
                            'limit' => '',
                            'offset' => '',
                            'finderQuery' => '',
                            'deleteQuery' => '',
                            'insertQuery' => ''
                    )
            );
            */
            var $hasMany = array(
                    'AlbumSong' => array(
                            'className' => 'AlbumSong',
                            'foreignKey' => 'song_id',
                            'dependent' => false,
                            'conditions' => '',
                            'fields' => '',
                            'order' => '',
                            'limit' => '',
                            'offset' => '',
                            'exclusive' => '',
                            'finderQuery' => '',
                            'counterQuery' => ''
                    )
            );
    }

    ?>
```

That is pretty much of it. For sake of brevity I removed validation
code.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you defined default conditions, in the association definitions (belongsTo, HABTM or hasMany), for tags model or comments model ?

Comment: Could you show us your models associations definiton and the content of the method where you make you call.

Comment: Could you please post the call you are using to create the sql.

Comment: Possibly related to this bug? http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/1069-occasional-rare-hard-to-trace-bug-sql-with-wrong-column-names-generated Please contribute any information to it you can.

Comment: I posted model association as Edit 4. Thanks.

Comment: @deceze My problem does sound a lot like what was reported in that ticket! Me too was executing it in a shell...

Answer (score 1):

I have had possibly the same problem.  The issue I encountered was cache collision in cake's implementation of caching the conditions (i.e. the WHERE clause) of a parsed sql.

For cake 1.3, the results of `DboSource::conditions()` and `DboSource::name()` are cached by default.  see: [DboSource](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/1.3/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php).  The cache uses crc32 hashing algorithm, which has a higher chance of collision.  Also, running queries in a tight loop can also increase the chance of collision.  That may explain why you have mismatching table names in the form of

```
select * from `table_A` where `table_B`.`field` ...
```

The solution was to set the data source to not do this caching.  So, try

```
$ds = $this->Comment->getDataSource();
$ds->cacheMethods = false;
```

before using methods that generate sql statements.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure not to have something like this:

```
class Tag extends AppModel
{
    public $belongsTo = array (
        'Comment' => array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'id' => 3, // Will add this condition on every query.
            ),
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: No I don't have something like that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this bug has anything to do with it, what version are you running:

[eb76ab9] Fixed issue where Model::saveAll() would incorrectly commit a transaction which was not started in that function call itself.

http://cakephp.org/changelogs/1.3.6

Answer (score 0):

try sticking $this-ModelName->create() before you set the id and save / find. all that does is clear any other data that is hanging around. a bit of a hack, but if it works could provide some clues to the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've been learning CakePHP in the last few months and this kind of thing occasionally drove me crazy. dogmatic's comment about using ->create() before your call can help if you've been using that model earlier in your function, it will reset the model's internal state so stale values don't interfere. That may not be your problem.

I agree with yvover and bancer that it's probably an issue of relationships. Posting your models (or links to the code) would be a big help. The thing that caught me more than once during development was thinking I was editing the model for a class when I was actually editing something else due to a name mismatch, so changes weren't reflected because my 'model' was never loaded.

Comment: I do call model->create() before all save calls. Do I need to do that for any ->find() calls too?

Comment: I posted model association as Edit 4. Thanks.